# NGX datatable with variable column width

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I would like to use ngx datable specifying a percentage in columns widths instead of a fixed width in pixels. So far I am able to do this using cellClass and headerClass but the table itself is still created with a fixed length that overflow my browser. Is there a way to do this.

Comment: Please refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228412/ngx-datatable-set-column-width-dynamically from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution and is to used fixed column type assigning a proportional length to each column. When the table is rendered the real length is calculated based on the proportion and the total width

Comment: Could you please share code piece , like how did you do ?